# Split a string which consists range of numbers by '- '

Tags: java, regex, string, split

I want to split a string which consists a range by '-',

**Example**

```
String range = "1 - 10";
```

I am doing something like this :

```
String[] s = range.split("-");
```

therefore `s[0]` will have start value and `s[1]` will have end value.

But this wont work for negative numbers.

**Example**

```
String range = "-1 - -10";
```

How can I handle negative range?

Comment: Use a regular expression. https://regex101.com/r/8D5FTu/2

Comment: @pkpkpk it's right there in the question: an array of strings, each containing a number that delimit the range

Comment: use `range.split(" - ");` ?

Comment: i need the start and end value i.e a string array with only 2 values.

Comment: there may not be a space for positive values it can be 1 - 10 or 1-10 depends on input

Comment: @Sakura please amend your question to include this last detail

Comment: @Sakura is this possible too ? `-1--10`

Comment: what should be the result of `1-10` and `-1-10`?

Comment: @YCF_L I really don't see why those two examples would be controversial. Considering there's no indication that the separator character may be missing, they're `["1", "10"]` and `["-1", "10"]`

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca In this case my first solution was not correct, I change it you can check

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would like to use Patterns instead of split in this situation with this regex like this :

```
(-?\d+)\s*-\s*(-?\d+)
```

Witch mean :

- `(-?\d+)` match first negative or positive number
- `\s*-\s*` followed by zero or more spaces then a hyphen `-` (I note it is required to make a range) then zero or more spaces
- `(-?\d+)` match second negative or positive number

The code can be :

```
String[] ranges = {"1 - 10", "-1 - -10", "1-10", "-10-5"};
String regex = "(-?\\d+)\\s*-\\s*(-?\\d+)";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);

for (String range : ranges) {
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(range);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        String number1 = matcher.group(1);
        String number2 = matcher.group(2);
        System.out.print(number1 + " " + number2);

    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

**Outputs**

```
1 10
-1 -10
1 10
-10 5
```

---

If your numbers can also have positive `+` sign you can change your regex to be

```
([+-]?\d+)\s*-\s*([+-]?\d+)
```

If your number can be a decimal you can use this regex :

```
([-+]?\d*\.?\d*)\s*-\s*([-+]?\d*\.?\d*)
```

Comment: it's not in the question, but I'm under the impression this would break for an inverted range with just the first number as negative, like `"-10-5"`

Comment: @ShubhenduPramanik it's perfectly clear, as the `-` is surely a range separator. In the second interpretation there's no separator at all

Comment: the above solution doesn't works for decimal numbers.

Comment: @Sakura if you want to work with decimals you can change your regex to this `String regex = "([-+]?\\d*\\.?\\d*)\\s*-\\s*([-+]?\\d*\\.?\\d*)";`